How to disable taskbar grouping in Windows 11?
I'm not talking about the taskbar grouping windows from the same application, but grouping two different windows when they are placed side by side. See screenshot.



There is an additional "Group | xxx" task being displayed, how can I get rid of it?
I believe this is a new feature of Windows 11.

@John both of the options are turned off (never)

Ungrouping of taskbar items is not supported yet; https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/list-of-changed-or-removed-featuresfunctionalities/1151c688-462a-4579-9164-8d11c78652c8 . Press WinKey+F and demand changes =)

You can disable this "Group | xxx" task by unchecking Settings > System > Multitasking > Snap windows > "Show my snapped windows when I hover  over taskbar apps, in Task View, and when I press Alt+Tab".


One workaround I've found is using Microsoft's PowerToys app.
It has a sub-app called FancyZones that lets you set zones to very easily snap your windows to (move them while holding shift). I've set up a zone layout with 2 halves of the screen and I have functionally the same thing as the windows snapping but without the group in the taskbar.
After you create the zone layout btw, make sure to turn off "space around zones" so they fully fill your screen, like the original snapping
